# how to delete add to cart option from product page

Tags: magento-1.9, css, addtocart

[image]

How to delete add to cart option from the product page? I have tried a lot but i didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: Which theme you are used for it ?

Comment: From which page you want to remove add to cart button, product list page or product view page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This can be solve by using css
2. If you know the css, please add

`.add-to-cart { display: none }`

3. Add css from the parent class.
4. You can find the parent class at the  place where you want to hide this.

Answer (score 3):

To remove add to cart from product list page edit list.phtml theme file

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/catalog/product/list.phtml`

and search for "**Add to Cart**" and remove html content related to `<button ...</button>`.